# Android - Compatibility Library v4 Exception (EdgeEffect) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: > android.widget.EdgeEffect

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using SherlockActionBar as well if that helps.

The line that triggered this exception is: `setContentView(R.layout.activity);`

The class I'm using  `extends SherlockFragmentActivity`

The application name is com.testapp.androidapp

and the class is: com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity.

I've tried this app on a few phones, and all work, except on this one device, the Nexus S.  While all devices have reported an actual version number for Android (4.0.1, 2.3.3), this is the only device to have a named version (IceCreamSandwich).

The question is, how can I ensure that this error doesn't occur? I don't need the effect (EdgeEffect) if that helps.

These are my imports:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

The summary of this exception is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.widget.EdgeEffect     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat.(EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:290)

The full StackTrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.testapp.androidapp/com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1859)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4215)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:244)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
>     at
>   com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsActivity.java:112)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4434)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1823)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)   ...
>   23 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.widget.EdgeEffect     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat.(EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:290)
>     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.(ViewPager.java:277)     ...
>   26 more android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:244)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
>     at
>   com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsActivity.java:112)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4434)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1823)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4215)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)   ...
>   23 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.widget.EdgeEffect     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat.(EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:290)
>     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.(ViewPager.java:277)     ...
>   26 more java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:244)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
>     at
>   com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsActivity.java:112)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4434)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1823)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4215)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.EdgeEffect     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat.(EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:290)
>     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.(ViewPager.java:277)     ...
>   26 more java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.EdgeEffect     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect(EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat.(EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:290)
>     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.(ViewPager.java:277)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:244)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
>     at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
>     at
>   com.testapp.androidapp.SwipeyTabsActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsActivity.java:112)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4434)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1823)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4215)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you scroll up in the LogCat to a bit before the exception occurs, you'll see a line that says something like `Unable to find the superclass for that class`.

There are only three reasons you will ever get this error:

1. The class genuinely doesn't exist. If you are using code from an official example and getting this, make sure you have the latest build of the library
2. You have not added the jar to your build path. To fix this, right click on the jar in Eclipse, and do Build Path ► Add to Build Path.
3. Your jar is not in the /libs folder. This happens when you have added the jar to the build path, but newer versions of ADT need it to be in /libs. Put it there and re-add it to the build path.

Comment: The thing is, this code has worked fine on at least 12 different models of devices. I've included the libraries properly.

Comment: Are you running a custom ROM, because my Nexus S reports a version number, not name.

Comment: No, that's the other weird thing, lol.  We saw this Nexus S laying around in the office and just started using it. First time I've seen a non Numeric version code.

Comment: I've seen those usually in Beta or unofficial or leaked builds of the OS. Have you tried flashing a stock firmware to it?